# pivot multiple views into single result table/view

Tags: python, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, pivot-table

I have 2 views as below:

experiments:

```
select * from experiments;
+--------+--------------------+-----------------+
| exp_id | exp_properties     | value           |
+--------+--------------------+-----------------+
|      1 | indicator:chemical | phenolphthalein |
|      1 | base               | NaOH            |
|      1 | acid               | HCl             |
|      1 | exp_type           | titration       |
|      1 | indicator:color    | faint_pink      |
+--------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

calculations:

```
select * from calculations;
+--------+------------------------+--------------+
| exp_id | exp_report             | value        |
+--------+------------------------+--------------+
|      1 | molarity:base          |  0.500000000 |
|      1 | volume:acid:in_ML      | 23.120000000 |
|      1 | volume:base:in_ML      |  5.430000000 |
|      1 | moles:H                |  0.012500000 |
|      1 | moles:OH               |  0.012500000 |
|      1 | molarity:acid          |  0.250000000 |
+--------+------------------------+--------------+
```

I managed to pivot each of these views individually as below:

experiments_pivot:

```
+-------+--------------------+------+------+-----------+----------------+
|exp_id | indicator:chemical | base | acid | exp_type  | indicator:color|
+-------+--------------------+------+------+-----------+----------------+
|   1   | phenolphthalein    | NaOH | HCl  | titration | faint_pink     |
+------+---------------------+------+------+-----------+----------------+
```

calculations_pivot:

```
+-------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
|exp_id | molarity:base | molarity:acid |   moles:H    |   moles:OH  | volume:acid:in_ML| volume:base:in_ML |
+-------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
|   1   | 0.500000000   | 0.250000000   | 0.012500000  | 0.012500000 | 23.120000000     | 5.430000000       |
+------+---------------------+------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

My question is how to get these two pivot results as a single row? Desired result is as below:

```
+-------+--------------------+------+------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
|exp_id | indicator:chemical | base | acid | exp_type  | indicator:color|molarity:base | molarity:acid |   moles:H    |   moles:OH | volume:acid:in_ML| volume:base:in_ML |
+-------+--------------------+------+------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
|   1   | phenolphthalein    | NaOH | HCl  | titration |  faint_pink    | 0.500000000  | 0.250000000   | 0.012500000  | 0.012500000 | 23.120000000     | 5.430000000      |
+------+---------------------+------+------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Database Used: Mysql

Important Note: Each of these views can have increasing number of rows. Hence I considered "dynamic pivoting" for each of the view individually.

For reference -- Below is a prepared statement I used to pivot `experiments` in MySQL(and a similar statement to pivot the other view as well):

```
set @sql = Null;
SELECT
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
   CONCAT(
     'MAX(IF(exp_properties = ''',
    exp_properties,
    ''', value, NULL)) AS ',
    concat("`",exp_properties, "`")
   )
 )into @sql
from experiments;

set @sql = concat(
  'select exp_id, ',
  @sql,
  ' from experiment group by exp_id'
  );
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

Comment: You mention application level code, so why not do all this stuff there?

Comment: @Strawberry The data which I posted here is just a sample. The real time data is humongous. so i don't want to load the entire data in RAM by using pandas or something and then perform operations on it which is very slower than getting an already formatted data from sql

Comment: I doubt that there's any difference.